# DataTables Export PDF with 100% Width

Tags: jquery, css, pdf, datatables

I am attempting to export my tables to PDF with a 100% width. I have tried the following but I have been unsuccessful

```
var settings={};
settings.buttons = [
    {
        extend:'pdfHtml5',
        text:'Export PDF',
        orientation:'landscape',
        customize : function(doc){ 
            doc.styles['table'] = { width:100% }
        }
    }
];
$('.dTable').dataTable(settings);
```

Answer (score 61):

Found an easier and quicker way to do it.

```
{
  extend: 'pdf',
  customize: function (doc) {
    doc.content[1].table.widths = 
        Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');
  }
}
```

What happens here is as so:

`doc.content[1].table.widths` is an array of widths for each column, and if each of them is a `'*'` it means that the table will fit 100% of the page with the columns distributed evenly.

`Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1)` creates an array in the length of all the columns of my table.

`.join('*')` creates a string from all the cells in the array with a `'*'` for each.

`.split('');` splits it back into an array.

Hope I helped someone along the way.

Comment: Works perfectlyy! Thanks

Comment: This one seems to work but goes beyond the right page margin

Comment: @darioxlz I can only guess that this part of the code is running before your table has loaded.

Comment: Finally something worked... BTW, `doc.content[1]` threw an error, `doc.content[2]` worked. I guess because I have title text as well.

Comment: It works fine on the portrait view. On landscape view, the table goes beyond the margin.

Comment: Is there something I can do to reduce some columns width and table width stay at 100%?

Comment: This code expands column widths to fit the page. But if you have a table wider than the page, it doesn't shrink to fit the page.

Answer (score 6):

After digging and digging I found that you simply need to add a width of '*' for each of the columns.  I created a simple function in order to create an array based on the number of td tags and included a colspan check.

```
var tbl = $('.dTable');
var settings={};
settings.buttons = [
    {
        extend:'pdfHtml5',
        text:'Export PDF',
        orientation:'landscape',
        customize : function(doc){
            var colCount = new Array();
            $(tbl).find('tbody tr:first-child td').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('colspan')){
                    for(var i=1;i<=$(this).attr('colspan');$i++){
                        colCount.push('*');
                    }
                }else{ colCount.push('*'); }
            });
            doc.content[1].table.widths = colCount;
        }
    }
];
$('.dTable').dataTable(settings);
```

Comment: The only solution I could get to work, thanks!!  Although I think `$i++` should just be `i++` as it's a JavaScript (rather than jQuery) variable declared earlier on the same line.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose the size you want for every column and let them fit the space you need. You just need to make some tuning of this:

```
"doc.content[1].table.widths = [90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90]; " : {
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    orientation: 'landscape',//orientamento stampa
    pageSize: 'A4', //formato stampa
    alignment: "center", //non serve a nnt ma gli dice di stampare giustificando centralmente
    titleAttr: 'PDF',   //titolo bottone
    exportOptions: {// quali colonne vengono mandate in stampa (indice posizionale)
        columns: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ]
    },
    customize : function(doc){ 
        doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left'; //giustifica a sinistra titoli colonne
        doc.content[1].table.widths = [90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90]; //costringe le colonne ad occupare un dato spazio per gestire il baco del 100% width che non si concretizza mai
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll make your answer easier to understand if you use code formatting and proper spelling/grammar. Also, you may want to stick to English in your code comments.

Comment: I'm having problem with widths. Error display is Cannot set property 'widths' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

Please try this is working fine
for entire data in centered align and pdf generating in full width: -

```
customize: function(doc) {
    doc.content[1].table.widths =Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');
    doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'center';
    doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'center';
},
```

Answer (score 2):

```
customize : function(doc){
    var colCount = new Array();
    var length = $('#reports_show tbody tr:first-child td').length;
    console.log('length / number of td in report one record = '+length);
    $('#reports_show').find('tbody tr:first-child td').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('colspan')){
            for(var i=1;i<=$(this).attr('colspan');$i++){
                colCount.push('*');
            }
        }else{ colCount.push(parseFloat(100 / length)+'%'); }
    });
}
```

Its working in my case. It count the number of data tag in the header. Then it assign 100 / (no of data tags) width to each of the data tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dtTbl = tbl.DataTable({
            dom: 'Bt',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: "pdfHtml5",
                    title: "Report",
                    customize: function(doc) {
                        console.log(doc.content)
                        doc.content.splice(0, 0, {
                            margin: [12, 0, 0, 12],
                            alignment: "center",
                        });

                        doc.content[2].table.widths = ["*", "*", "*"];
                    }]
            })
```

This is what I did and it worked. I only have 3 headers so I inserted three asterisks in the table widths.

Answer (score 0):

This work excellent... Is adaptable. Edited for me. Change the class (.Datatable) for the id or class of your table

```
customize: function(doc) {
    var colCount = new Array();
    var tr = $('.DataTable tbody tr:first-child');
    var trWidth = $(tr).width();

    var length = $('.DataTable tbody tr:first-child td').length;
    $('.DataTable').find('tbody tr:first-child td').each(function() {
        var tdWidth = $(this).width();
        var widthFinal = parseFloat(tdWidth * 115);
        widthFinal = widthFinal.toFixed(2) / trWidth.toFixed(2);
        if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= $(this).attr('colspan'); $i++) {
                colCount.push('*');
            }
        } else {
            colCount.push(parseFloat(widthFinal.toFixed(2)) + '%');
        }
    });
    doc.content[1].table.widths = colCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi for me this solution work

```
customize: function (doc) {
    doc.content[0].table.widths = "*";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item.table.body[0].length < 10) {
    item.table.widths = Array(item.table.body[0].length +1).join('*').split('');
}
```

If there are more than 10 columns in dynamic column visibility, this shape query code provides the necessary dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowCount = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1].rows.length;
var colCount = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody') 
[0].rows[0].cells.length;
for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

 for (c = 0; c < colCount; c++) {
     var cellVal = parseFloat(doc.content[1].table.body[1][c].text);
     if (isNaN(cellVal) != true) {
         doc.content[1].table.body[i][c].alignment = 'right';
     }
     else {
         doc.content[1].table.body[i][c].alignment = 'left';
     }
 }

 doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 9;

 doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 9;

 doc.content[1].table.widths =
     Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');
```

};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#table_ID").DataTable({
        "responsive": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                },
                customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.styles.tableBodyEven.alignment = 'center';
                    doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.alignment = 'center';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score -1):

You should look for where it says **t.table.widths** in the 'pdfmake.js' file and change the value to '*'.

> t.table.widths="*"