# Jquery DataTable centre data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, datatables

Using the PDF button function I have managed to get my data table to stretch across the page but how can I get my data in my data table to be centre on the PDF output?

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    customize: function(doc) {
      console.dir(doc)
      doc.content[1].table.widths =
        Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');
    }
  }],
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lv4srdqo/

Comment: If you mean that you want to centre align all the data cells, you just need to add this to your customize funtion: `doc.content[1].alignment = 'center';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your customize add:

```
    doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.alignment = 'center'; 
    doc.styles.tableBodyEven.alignment = 'center';
```

ref: [Giuliano Knoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534490/6373355)